# Magento 2 "Something went wrong." in admin after move to another server

Tags: magento2, error, transfer

I have moved a magento 2 store to a vps but I cannot configure it.

When I am trying to access Orders in admin I am getting an eror message "Something went wrong.". If I look at console I see it gets 500 (Internal Server Error) on a link, if try to open that link it says this:

```
Initialization error component, check the spelling of the name or the correctness of the call.
#0 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(139): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepareData(NULL)
#1 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render.php(25): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create(NULL)
#2 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render->execute()
#3 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#7 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Ui\\Cont...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#8 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Ui\\Cont...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Array,  'designLoader')
#12 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/Design.php(39): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\Design->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Ui\\Cont...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#16 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(140): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#19 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#20 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#23 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#24 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#25 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(140): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#28 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#29 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#31 /home/hiddenuser/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#32 {main}
```

Where is the problem? Any solution will be perfect.

Comment: Yes, in our case it was a wrong nginx configuration.  Missing the part in bold

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

Comment: Your 4th  line find error in  Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render->execute()  
**
Render extends Render class **
so find in 'excute() function'  remove it "  return parent::execute();"

Comment: Thanks, where exaclty to find this code?

Comment: Magento_main_folder\vendor\magento\module-ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render.php

Comment: replace return parent::execute(); with return;

Comment: but there is not any Render.php file

Comment: Sorry i miss directory
Magento_main_folder\vendor\magento\module-ui\Controller\Admi‌​nhtml\Index\Render.p‌​hp

Comment: Yes found the file but there is not return parent::execute(); . May should I try to add it ?

Comment: which server you used ?

Comment: it's a vps centos 6 nginx and php 7

Comment: It seemed wrong server configuration

Comment: where should be the problem. at nginx ?